# Using post, get and function

Tags: php, mysql, post, get

This is my function codes

```
function icerikduzenle($a,$b,$c)
{
global $veriyolu;
$menuid=$c;
$icerik=$b;
$icerik_id=$a;
$guncelle=mysql_query("update icerik set icerik='$icerik' , menu_id='$menu_id' where icerik_id='$icerik_id'",$veriyolu);

if($guncelle){
             echo "<script>alert(' İçerik düzenlendi! ')</script>";
             echo "<meta http-equiv='Refresh' content='0; URL=yonetim.php?menu=2'>";
             }else{
             echo "<script>alert(' !! İçerik düzenlenemedi !! ')</script>";
             echo "<meta http-equiv='Refresh' content='0; URL=yonetim.php?menu=2'>";             
             }
}
```

I think I have problems with _post vars. List datas with no errors but is not update datas

This is main codes
I didnt prefer connection tables in mysql i used 2 sqls
I think post vars dont go anywhere

```
$iceriksql="select * from icerik order by menu_id asc";
$iceriksorgu= mysql_query($iceriksql);
echo "<table>";
while($iceriksonuc=mysql_fetch_array($iceriksorgu))
{
echo "<form method='post' action='yonetim.php?menu=2&icerikid={$iceriksonuc["icerik_id"]}&git=icerikduzenle'>";
$menusql= "select * from menu order by menu_id asc";
$menusorgu = mysql_query($menusql);
echo "<tr><td><select name='menu_id'>";
    while ($menusonuc=mysql_fetch_array($menusorgu))
    {
    if ($menusonuc['menu_id']==$iceriksonuc['menu_id'])
    {
    echo "<option value='{$menusonuc["menu_id"]}' selected>{$menusonuc["menu"]}</option>";
    }
    else
    {
    echo "<option value='{$menusonuc["menu_id"]}'>{$menusonuc["menu"]}</option>";
    }
    }
echo "</select></td>";
echo "<td><textarea name='icerik'>{$iceriksonuc["icerik"]}</textarea></td><td><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Düzenle' /></td></tr>";
echo "</form>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

This is last part of my codes

```
switch ($_GET['git']){ 
case "icerikduzenle";
icerikduzenle($_REQUEST['icerik_id'],$_REQUEST['icerik'],$_REQUEST['menu_id']);
break;
}
```

Comment: Can you `echo` the query here ?

Comment: Variable `$veriyolu` is your resource identifier and it is global to that function ?

Comment: I added global $veriyolu; it looks working but do not change data in mysql

Answer (score 0):

```
case "icerikduzenle";
```

has to be

```
case "icerikduzenle":
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Case must be colon (:)

```
switch ($_GET['git']){ 
    case "icerikduzenle" :
                 icerikduzenle($_REQUEST['icerik_id'],$_REQUEST['icerik'],$_REQUEST['menu_id']);
                 break;
}
```